# How to Launch Geeqie

Tags: xubuntu

I believe that I installed it correctly (went through the listed configure, make , and make install commands listed) but I can't seem to actually launch the program...

What I've done so far:

configure (this went off without a hitch)
make (same with this)
make check (a-ok)

Then - make install - and I think this is where the trouble might be:

make install

Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
Making install in icons
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
Making install in svg
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons/svg'
make[4]: Entering directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons/svg'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for`install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons/svg'
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons/svg'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
make[4]: Entering directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for`install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src/icons'
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/bin"
  /usr/bin/install -c geeqie '/usr/local/bin'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/geeqie’: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/amhorne/Downloads/geeqie-1.1/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: downloaded from where? how are you launching the program?  Errors that you see from a terminal?

Comment: downloaded from http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/ - the problem is that I don't know how to launch the program - the install directions note that 'make install' will install the package commands under /usr/local/bin but I don't see them there - did I somehow install wrong?

Comment: add this to your question.  describe exactly how you make & installed this.  Copy and paste the output - use paste.ubuntu.com and add the link to your question.  This is  needed to help us see exactly what you have done.

Comment: use `sudo make install` to install the application - what happens then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing

> /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/geeqie’: Permission denied

means that the installer does not have enough permissions to write to the folder in question - i.e. /usr/local/bin

This is expected.  Ordinary users should never have the right to directly write to this folder.

You need to give the installer elevated privileges - this is done by using `sudo`

`sudo` is available to accounts that have administrator rights.

Thus, if you do run the installer thus:

`sudo make install`

this will install the application into /usr/local

You should then be able to run the application.